# Making 3 column in a page container without using table format

Tags: html, css, web

I am making a responsive website, and in container page there are 3 columns.

I want html tag that is more useful to make 3 column or 4 column format other than `table format` 
like in **[THIS](http://postimg.org/image/o35fbmwq3/)** picture

```
 <div id = "main">
        row 1
        row 2 
        row 3
 </div><!--end main-->
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your concern are only latest browsers. Then You may think about using CSS new feature **[multi-column](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Using_multi-column_layouts)** layouts.

A small CSS code is here with a **[DEMO](http://jsbin.com/rizomawikoto/1/edit)** link.

```
.three-col {
  -moz-column-count: 3;
  -moz-column-gap: 20px;
  -webkit-column-count: 3;
  -webkit-column-gap: 20px;
  column-count: 3;
  column-gap: 20px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

simply You can use [Columnizer](http://welcome.totheinter.net/columnizer-jquery-plugin/)

The Columnizer jQuery Plugin will automatically layout your content in newspaper column format. You can specify either column width or a static number of columns. And, of course, it’s easy to use!

Comment: look at this responsive implementation of table less columns [link](http://webdesignerwall.com/tutorials/responsive-column-layouts)